# Смена background-color при скролле - jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как можно реализовать подобную вещь:
есть блоки (обязательно более двух, в моем случаем четыре), у всех разный цвет фона. Нужно, чтобы при скролле страницы вверх/вниз, цвет из одного плавно перетекал в другой!

Пример сайта, где это реализовано (второй-третий-четвертый блок): http://sfcd.com.

Нашел способы как это реализовано на примере двух блоков на всю страницу:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/animatio...colorizer.html. Нужно, повторяюсь, четыре цвета.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: https://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG?editors=1010

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cgspicer/V4qh9/